# KnockoutJs Setting Selected Option in a Select tag is not working

Tags: knockout.js

In the code linked below, the displayed option when the page loads is always "X".

I am using two different ways to attempt to set the value to "z", yet it is never getting set.

What am I doing wrong? How do I set this to "z"?

HTML:

```
<select id="TestList" data-bind='options: Options, value: SelectedOption'></select>
<br />
<select id="TestList" data-bind='options: Options, selectedOptions: SelectedOption2'></select>
```

Javascript:

```
    var TestViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.Options = ko.observableArray(['x', 'y', 'z']);
        self.SelectedOption = ko.observable(self.Options[2]);
        self.SelectedOption2 = ko.observableArray([self.Options[2]]);
    };



    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
    });
```

(Code: http://jsfiddle.net/cleverpatrick/huqNd/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `options` binding but how you've set the initial values in `SelectedOption` and `SelectedOption2`.

Because `Options` is a `ko.observableArray` you need to get its underlaying array with calling it as  function with `self.Options()`.

So you've missed the `()` in your code, the correct version should look like this:

```
self.SelectedOption = ko.observable(self.Options()[2]);
self.SelectedOption2 = ko.observableArray([self.Options()[2]]);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZEvy/).